# Jquery issue trying to Parse Json

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I dont know why but i've been having issues trying to parse the following json:

```
{
    "output": "",
    "status": -1,
    "system_messages": {
        "error": [],
        "success": [
            "You have added Steven as a friend."
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I parse 'success' out using jquery?

Comment: `console.log(data.system_messages.success[0]);` is this you need?

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/7ujks8x4/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you really have, you need either:

```
// You really have JSON (that is, you have a *string* containing
// what you quoted):
var data = JSON.parse(theString); // Or ... = jQuery.parseJSON(theString)
console.log(data.system_messages.success[0]);
```

or just

```
// You don't have JSON (anymore), it's already an object:
console.log(yourVariableName.system_messages.success[0]);
```

Note that if you're getting that back as the result of an ajax call and you used jQuery to make the ajax call, jQuery probably *already* parsed it for you and only only need the second example above. Similarly, if you have what you've quoted literally in code, then it's not JSON, it's a JavaScript object initializer and you only need the second example above.

Note that since `success` is an array, we needed `[0]` at the end.

Live Example:

```js
var theString =
  '{' +
     '"output": "",' +
     '"status": -1,' +
     '"system_messages": {' +
      '"error": [],' +
      '"success": [' +
        '"You have added Steven as a friend."' +
      ']' +
    '}' +
  '}';
var data = JSON.parse(theString);
snippet.log(data.system_messages.success[0]);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like

```
var obj={
    "output": "",
    "status": -1,
    "system_messages": {
        "error": [],
        "success": [
            "You have added Steven as a friend."
        ]
    }
}
alert(obj.system_messages["success"][0]);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/29/)